# Process WSDL to include only specific functions

Tags: java, web-services, xslt, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a WSDL file provided by a service I'm using. It contains a large number of functions and I'm only interested in one.

How can I  "refactor" the WSDL file and generate a new one that includes only the function I'm interested in?

I'm using the JDK's wsimport to process the WSDL file so a JAX-WS solution would be great, but if you know how to do it with XSLT (by processing the WSDL file as a simple XML file) that's fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some special reason why additional methods in WSDL bother you? I mean, there is no any harm in having them, you simply call your method and ignore the others :) Having said that, there is always an option of manually editing the WSDL (unfortunately, there is no `wsimport` option to import only specific method). Just erase all unnecessary methods and their associated elements from the WSDL and re-generate the WS client from new WSDL. Be careful to store and retrieve WSDL locally with your application, and Web service call should be successful regardless of changed WSDL. In case that you are afraid to erase the methods manually, there is XML and WSDL plugin for Netbeans. You can open your WSDL there, and you will see all Web methods in the designer. Just click all methods (they are called "operations" here) that you want to remove and they will disappear from the document without any fear that you messed up something. An example follows:

[image]

Actually, there is a similar, but reverse situation when you build Web service client from the remote WSDL and then WS developer updates the original WSDL with new methods. Web service call will still be successful if you stored WSDL locally; regardless of new methods being added.

See also:

- [Developing client application with locally packaged WSDL](http://metro.java.net/guide/ch02.html#developing-client-application-with-locally-packaged-wsdl)

Comment: The reason is that it's a huge WSDL while I only need one method. It's so huge that it affects loading times of my wsimport-ed classes and application build times. Manual editing is too risky and I would like an automated process to reduce the WSDL to my needs. I do save a local copy of the WSDL because otherwise using the remote one makes everything even slower. Thanks!

Comment: @gnobal - You are welcome! Don't be afraid of manual editing, you can always backup the original file in case that something goes wrong. I have done it many times (not to praise, but to assure you that there is nothing to be scared of). I recalled one more way to do it (less risky), so I've updated the answer.